# Does it make sense to write unit tests that are just testing if functions are called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have the following code:

```py
def task_completed(task):
    _update_status(task, TaskStatus.COMPLETED)
    successful_task(task)


def task_pending(task):
    _update_status(task, TaskStatus.PENDING)
    successful_task(task)


def task_canceled(task):
    _update_status(task, TaskStatus.CANCELED)
    process_task(task)


def successful_task(task):
    process_task(task)
    send_notification(task)


def process_task(task):
    assign_user(task)
    notify_user(task)
    cleanup(task)


def _update_status(task, status):
    task.status = status
    task.save(update_fields=['status'])
```

I have written the following tests:

```py
def test_task_completed(mocker, task):
    mock_successful_task = mocker.patch('services.successful_task')
    task_completed(task)

    assert task.status == TaskStatus.COMPLETED
    mock_successful_task.called_once_with(task)


def test_task_pending(mocker, task):
    mock_successful_task = mocker.patch('services.successful_task')
    task_pending(task)

    assert task.status == TaskStatus.PENDING
    mock_successful_task.called_once_with(task)


def test_task_canceled(mocker, task):
    mock_process_task = mocker.patch('services.process_task')
    task_pending(task)

    assert task.status == TaskStatus.CANCELED
    mock_process_task.called_once_with(task)


def test_successful_task(mocker, task):
    mock_process_task = mocker.patch('services.process_task')
    mock_send_notification = mocker.patch('notifications.send_notification')

    mock_process_task.called_once_with(task)
    mock_send_notification.called_once_with(task)


def test_process_task(mocker, task):
    mock_assign_user = mocker.patch('users.assign_user')
    mock_notify_user = mocker.patch('notifications.notify_user')
    mock_cleanup = mocker.patch('utils.cleanup')

    mock_assign_user.called_once_with(task)
    mock_notify_user.called_once_with(task)
    mock_cleanup.called_once_with(task)
```

As you can see some tests like `test_successful_task` and `test_process_task` are just testing if specific functions are called.

But does it make sense to write a test for this or do I understand something wrong and my unit tests are just bad? I don't know another solution how I should test these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White box tests can be useful to detect some regression or to assert that a specific action is made.
For example you can verify that you don't interact with your DB in this particular case or that you've correctly called the notification service.

However, the drawback is that you're likely to change the test when you change the code, because you're test is very tied to the implementation.
This can be painful when you are refactoring, because you also need to refactor the test. You could forget an assertion or a step and create a false positive test with a regression.

I would use it only if it makes sens and if you need it to assert what's going on in details.

You can search on the web TDD: London vs Detroit.
You'll find interesting stuff.

Comment: I found "london vs chicago", too. Is Chicago and Detroit the same in this context?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Is it better if I test the process_task function by checking if an user was assigned to the given task and the the user received a message. Because that is the purpose of the function and this is basically the state I want after the function was called. But I also have unit tests for the functions inside the process_task function so the code would be a bit duplicated.

Comment: You mean, just testing process_task and remove the other tests ?

Comment: I mean testing all functions again that are used in test_process_task because I use multiple functions together. I don't want to delete the existing tests.

Comment: I think that if your services are well isolated and tested, yes you can validate your test when you know that the service has been called.   
But sometimes you want to make a complete end-to-end test and then you have to assert everything again. In this case, you should refactor your test and make a function that does all the assertions, so you can reuse it in the integration and ent-to-end tests.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel That is a really good point because I want to write an integration test later which is basically testing the same. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, tests like these are very brittle because they depend on implementation details. A unit test should only be concerned with the results of the method being tested. Ideally, this means asserting against the return value. If there are side effects, you can assert those instead. But then you should probably look at those side effects and find a different solution that doesn't require them.

Answer (score 4):

I would say no, they're not useful.

Unit tests are supposed to test functionality, here's some input, I call this, here's my result, does it match what I expect? Things needs to be clear and verifiable.

When you have a test which verifies a method has been called, what do you really have? 
Pure uncertainty. Ok, a thing has been called, but how is that useful? You are not verifying a result, the method you're calling can do a million things and you have no idea what it does.

Code calling a method is an implementation detail and your unit tests are not supposed to have that kind of knowledge.

Why do we write unit tests? 
- to check functionality
- to help refactoring

If you need to change your tests every time your code changes then you haven't really accomplished one of the main reasons for unit testing.

If your code changes and that method is not called anymore, then what? 
You now have to go and change the test? Change it to what though? If your next move is to remove the test then why did you have in the first place?

What if someone else has to deal with this issue, 6 months down the road? There is no documentation to check and see why is there a test checking a method has been called?

Bottom line, a test like this has zero value and all it does is introduce uncertainty.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the purpose of unit tests, though it does have uses. Unit tests aim to improve the quality of the code by testing functionality and results-- it would be more beneficial to write unit tests to test the functionality of each method called.

With that being said, if you have one function that calls 4 other functions and you want to check if they actually get executed in your main block of code, then this makes sense. But you should definitely be writing unit tests for your submethods as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, yes.

When you design a test, you know that you have to deal with 4 elements

- pre-conditions (context)
- inputs
- outputs
- post-conditions (side effects)

We all agree that it would be more easy to test and code if the beahviour of the function under test depended only from inputs and outputs, but in some case this cannot happen, especially when your logic deals with I/O and/or its goal is to issue a mutation of the application state. This means that your test have to be aware of post-conditions. But what can make us sure that a post-condition is met?

pick this method

```
public class UserService
{
    public void addUser(User toAdd)
}
```

this method adds a user on the database; in a more elegant way, we can say that adds the User to a collection, which is abstracted by the repository semantic. So the side effect of the method is that a userRepository.save(User user) is called. You can mock this method and expect that has been called once with given argument, or make the test fail

Obiviously this can be achivied only if the method has been mocked, so the test is not influenced from the behaviour of a unit that is not under test.

I recognize that the drawback is to make the test brittle, but at the same time

1. in tdd, it makes fail tests that don't call the mocked function, so the test states "hey, the addUser relies upon the UserRepository.save()!" if you're into this style
2. The test will be broken if the dependent function interface changes, but we don't want to change interface often, am I right?
3. before to add dependencies to your method you will think twice, this is an hint to write cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense. However, I would look at [`unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with)